# Best way to hang a bicycle from a ceiling pipe

Tags: storage

I've just moved to a new place, and it's pretty small, so I'm looking to put my bike out of the way by hanging it from a (plenty sturdy) pipe that runs along my ceiling. At the moment I've got it jury-rigged with bungee cords, but that's obviously not a long-term solution. It seems that most of the hooks sold online are either wall-mount (not viable for me since my walls are concrete) or screw into the ceiling (not viable for the same reason). Is there any other method - such as hooks that are meant to actually hang off of something else - that might work here?

**My current setup**
[image]

Comment: What are you doing with the space below it?  I would build a simple unit where the bike is on the floor with shelves above.

Comment: All you need is two large S hooks for the wheels.  (Bend them yourself or maybe find "butcher hanging hooks" somewhere.)   If you get fancy you could use pipe hangers and some large storage hooks.

Comment: Your landlord might not like this.

Comment: @Blam - It's hard to describe the layout of the room, but it works out such that leaving it on the floor would be considerably more in the way (even though it's not hung above head height).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have room to hang the bike vertically by the rear wheel, it's pretty easy to assemble what you need from parts at the hardware store.

Look for a [cushioned hanger](http://www.lowes.com/pd_267966-46882-24195PEXLG_4294646759__?productId=3721860&Ns=p_product_qty_sales_dollar%7C1&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNs%3Dp_product_qty_sales_dollar%7C1&facetInfo=) to put the rear wheel in.

Then Google [pipe hangers](https://www.google.com/search?q=bike%20pipe%20hanger&oq=bike%20pipe%20hanger&aqs=chrome..69i57.4565j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=pipe%20hangers) to find something to attach the hanger above to the pipe.

You could also look for a coated S hook for the bike wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's not a carbon frame (I don't dare go near them) I would try to hang it from the frame near the saddle.  I'm guessing with suspension forks and a rack it will probably balance just forward of the saddle.  A nice wide (e.g. 200mm) single hook would seem to me to be the way to go - an S-hook but made of sheet material, or 2 S-hooks joined together with a spacer. A snug fit and/or friction around the pipe will make it easier to put in - both can be achieved by foam sheet in a flat solution, or pipe insulation wrapped round a hook.

A pair of wall hooks could be bolted back-to-back (possibly bent a little further than as sold) to form S-hooks, with a sheet of plywood/aluminium between the held in by the same bolts to space the 2 hooks apart.  Gary E's answer (+1) gives an idea of some products you might start from - browse around the Lowes link to find something wide enough for the pipe.

This would give you a single lift with no strapping involved, but depending on where you live and who else has access it might be worth keeping a spare cable lock looped over the pipe to lock through the frame and deter casual opportunists.